# PHP 5.5 vs 7.4 TTFB slower

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.5, time-to-first-byte

I have recently copied my website to a other server (which performs way better than the old one). I am running 7.4 on that new website, but I noticed the Time to the First Byte went up from 200 ms to like 600ms. I thought it might be the server that is acting up so I started a identical server on my old provider but with 7.4 as well, and there I had the same results.

So my question is, why does my TTFB increase from 200 to 600 ms going from php 5.5 to 7.4?

Maybe any of  you encountered this same problem and have sucessfully changed some things.

Greetings

Grumpy

Comment: Could this be as simple as a cache somewhere in the transit not being aware of your new site yet

Comment: are you sure you configured 7.4 to match 5.5 e.g. is opcache enabled, are the opcache settings similar. Are you using FPM and if so are the pool settings comparable?